How to catch action RecaptchaAction or checking if the email provided is in Authentication in Firebase?
I need advice on checking if the email provided is in Authentication in Firebase or how to get the RecaptchaAction action caught because instead of my notification on the screen I get this error in the logs. What am I doing wrong and could I correct.
public void signIn(View v){
        getCred(); // get the email and password from TextView
        if (signIn()){ // validate email and password is not blank
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this, MoreUI.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "signInWithEmail:failure",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

In the Logs i get
Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired.

But I need to see a toast on the screen indicating failure
About checking if the given email is already in Athentication in Firebase the only solution is to set up a server that would communicate with Admin SDK or are there any other ways to make it work on the client side?
